# Is the following matrix symmetric, skew-symmetric, or orthogonal? Find its eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

\begin{pmatrix}a&k&k\\ k&a&k\\ k&k&a\end{pmatrix}

I know that this matrix is symmetric as trasnposition on it leaves it unchanged.

since the determinant is $(a-\lambda)^3 + 2k^3 - 3k^2(a-\lambda)$
and finding for eigenvalues would equate the determinant to $0$
how do you find the eigenvalues and eigenvector for this?
Is there any certain rules of eigenvalues for symmetric matrices?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The matrix is symmetric and in the case $k=0$ also skew-symmetric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : The $3\times 3$-matrix containing $9$ $k's$ is singular. This allows you to find one (double) eigenvalue immediately. Also , it is not diifficult to find an eigenvector, for example $[2,-1,-1]$ to this eigenvalue. $a+2k$ is an eigenvalue as well with eigenvector $[1,1,1]$